# Wxwidgets for server programming (ftp apachelike)

Tags: c++, apache, networking, boost, wxwidgets

Would wxwidgets be performant enough to handle say thousands of sockets? From what I saw it only has events related to it but nothing as close to iocp from winsock or the io service in boost. Should I change my toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

wxWidgets is a GUI framework.  It happens to have a wrapper for native socket libraries as a convenience, but it is probably not a great idea to use this for something requiring thousands of sockets, where boost::asio would be more likely to be successful.  Which GUI framework you use is a matter of taste and experience - use the one you like and are most familiar with.  However, it will probably turn out better if the GUI and the socket server are designed to run as separate, co-operating processes - which further unlinks the choice of socket library and GUI framework.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you what you think about QT's networking framework? Will that be suitable for my purpose?

Comment: Same answer here:  boost::asio for the sockets, you favourite GUI framework for the GUI.  I am not familiar with QT - does it have a good socket library?  Better than boost::asio?

Comment: Or do you mean Qt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)?  Again this is a GUI framework, not a netweorking framework.  You should try and get the distinction clear in your mind. Many GUI frameworks offer socket support, just for convenience, but you need something more heavy duty.